# firebase.storage() takes either no argument or a Firebase App instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

Actually, the title is more or less the whole explanation of the problem.
I am trying to use Firebase inside my React app, which also uses NextJS and the problem is that I cannot get storage to work.

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import uuid from 'uuid/v4'

// Init
try {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: 'apiKey',
    authDomain: 'authDomain',
    databaseURL: 'dbUrl',
    projectId: 'projID',
    storageBucket: 'storageBucket',
    messagingSenderId: 'id'
  })
} catch (err) {
  if (!/already exists/.test(err.message)) {
    console.error('Firebase initialization error', err.stack)
  }
}

console.log(firebase.app().name) // <- name

// References
const database = firebase.database()
const storage = firebase.storage().ref() // <- the problem 
const documentImageStorage = storage.child('images/')
const documentsRef = database.ref('/documents/')
const documentsRequestsRef = database.ref('/requests/')
```

So, as I run the code I can confirm that the app works as the database works properly and the name **([default])** is returned correctly, but the line in which the storage reference is defined returns an error:

```
Firebase: firebase.storage() takes either no argument or a Firebase App instance. (app/invalid-app-argument).
```

Any ideas why this might happen? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out how to make it work!

```
export const storage = process.browser ? firebase.storage().ref() : undefined
```

This way, storage part, which is unavailable on the backend isn't loaded, but on the frontend it is and everything works perfectly!

Thanks for both answers!

Answer (score 1):

(Firebase Storage JS dev)

I was able to reproduce your error in Next.js. I'm not super familiar with it, but I understand Next.js does React-y server-side rendering, so the code you write for your page will generally be executed in the node server.

Unfortunately, Storage [isn't supported in node](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/18) right now, which includes server-side rendering contexts (feel free to leave a comment in the Github issue about your use case).

It should work in normal React apps (i.e. client-side code) though.

**EDIT: found a (barely) workaround**

The code appears to not crash in Next.js if you add an import at the top of the file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import _s from 'firebase/storage'
import uuid from 'uuid/v4'
...
```

Regardless, the Storage library still isn't supported in node. Most anything interesting (uploading objects, getting object metadata) won't work, so unless all you wanted to do was call `storage.toString()` somewhere this probably doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase docs states that you save storage service reference to variable, then save storage reference to different variable.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference

So I would do this like so:

`const storage = firebase.storage();
const storageRef = storage.ref();`

You can also put path to your storage folder to get reference for it, like this:

```
const documentImageStorage = storage.ref('/images/');
```

Comment: `firebase.storage().ref()` is valid, working code, you can actually see it in the Full Example at the bottom of the page you linked: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference#full_example - I added an answer with my understanding of the actual problem.